# Android SDK Manager - Fetching URL error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

> Fetching http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>
> Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>
> Fetching URL: http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
>
> Done loading packages.
>
> Fetching http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>
> Failed to fetch URL http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason:
>   Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>
> Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>
> Fetching URL: http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
>
> Failed to fetch URL http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: 
>   Socket Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>
> Done loading packages.

I've been trying to fix this for ages...
Already tried:

- Disabling firewall and antivirus
- Checking the "force https:// ... sources to be fetched using http:// ..." box
- Checking for updates (Help tab)
- Installing new software (Help tab)
- Setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
- Reinstalling SDK, Eclipse and Java
- Setting environment variables
- Running android.bat from CMD
- Doing the "copy tools folder" fix
  Also, I don't use any proxy.
  Seriously, I've tried everything...
  This is what I get when running android.bat from CMD:

> `Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
>   get host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
>   Apr 23, 2013 4:24:52 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryCo
>   nnect
>   INFO: Retrying connect`

Comment: Google search yielded this page: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41231

Comment: Already tried that...